# Lambda convert to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I don't know anything about lambda, and I can't even read a complicated [lambda expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). I have this lambda code below that I want to convert into LINQ, but I don't know how.

```
var train = db.sample1
            .Join(db.sample2, a => a.CertificateId, b => b.CertificateId, (a, b) => new { a, b })
            .Where(x => x.a.Year.Value.Year == year && x.a.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId && x.a.IsApproved.Value && x.b.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
            .Select(z => z.a).Distinct();
```

What I have tried so far and got stuck on:

```
var train = (from c in db.sample1
    join in ts sample2 where a.CertificateId equals b.CertificateId
    ......
```

Comment: this already is linq (which is using lambda expressions)

Comment: @slawekwin sorry then I am new to programming. What I want is convert it into linq expression

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but for what reason?
Are you having problems with the query or do you want to increase the readability?

Comment: @Sasquatch I want to read that query cuz I can't read a lambda expression

Comment: Lambdas are beautiful. Why would you want that horrid syntax?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq as i mention I cant read lambdas :) sorry

Comment: Why not learn how to read lambda expressions then? For example, the lambda equivalent of `public int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }` is `(int a, int b) => { return a + b; }`. Parameters go before the `=>` arrow, the method body comes after it. Parameter types can often be inferred, so they're often left out: `(a, b) => { return a + b; }`. Also, lambda's are often short methods that only contain a single expression, so there's simplified syntax for that: `(a, b) => a + b`.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I am starting to read some blog about lambda the more I read it the it becomes complicated to me but I will try hard to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda LINQ is still a link expression. However, the statement should look something like this:

```
var train2 = (from c in db.sample1
    join t in db.sample2
        on c.CertificateId equals t.CertificateId
        where c.Year.Value.Year == year && c.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId
        && c.IsApproved.Value && t.EndDate >= DateTime.Now
        select c).Distinct();
```

Comment: I prefer lambda linq also. at runtime comprehension gets complied to lambda linq anyway so it truly makes little difference in my opinion.

Comment: @Steffsww Can I convert it w/o using a join?. Possible? Yes / No?

Comment: @Kiv2 You can, but why? Avoiding join here will just make the query even more convoluted

Comment: @Martheen just want see how it looks like :) I want to look new things and study it

Comment: @Kiv2 If you understand how [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040(v=vs.110).aspx) works, it's pretty simple to rewrite it yourself (into a horrible loops). Writing with join means you're thinking in stream instead of inefficient reinventing the wheel. Plus anyone else who read your code can understand it quickly. Learn LINQ, embrace it.

Comment: About joining I learn it just a while ago maybe about a month now.

Comment: @Martheen Can you show it to me the linq converted w/o join?

Comment: @Kiv2 Have you grok the concept of 'join'? Just loop on sample1 & sample2, take elements where their CertificateID is equal. The linq equivalent without join will be either so ugly or less efficient.