# What really lambda looks like? (not a linq lambda expression)

Tags: c#, lambda

I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786992/lambda-convert-to-linq) in converting a lambda to linq. And I am thinking about what `slawekwin` said in comment.

*this already is linq (which is using lambda expressions)*

Can someone please give me an example of what really lambda looks like?. Not in Linq Lambda Expression. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you meant to ask what a lambda expression looks like, but what LINQ looks like, and the difference between the two.

Comment: What you're trying to do there is change the LINQ fluent interface with lambda expressions, to LINQ query expressions.

Comment: @BoltClock the accepted answer is lambda expression right?. Is it difference in linq lambda expression?

Comment: No, it's a query expression.

Comment: LINQ is simply a collection of methods which make life easy. Things like `Where()` `Select()` and so on. Most (all?) of them leverage lambdas, which are anonymous functions.

Comment: @BoltClock ow sorry.. I mean the question is in linq lambda expression?

Comment: @BoltClock As I read the existing post. The question of the user in the thread that I read is in method syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda functions are a language construct of defining a function.

LINQ is a library of functions. Many of these functions takes functions as parameters to compare or select elements from your lists. Therefore it is very common to use lambda functions to specify these parameter functions. Simple because that makes puts the definition of what it is supposed to do where you actually use it. But there is nothing preventing you from NOT using lambda functions with LINQ.